# Wrong views position on iPhone X

Tags: ios, ios11, iphone-x

My app looked well on all devices, until I tested it on new iPhone X (See the attached screenshot).
Search bar is under navigation bar, and it's awful. I tried playing with new safe area insets, edgesForExtendedLayout, but with no success. Maybe someone can help with this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigations I figured out how to fix my issue. I had to align the search view according to the safe area. See the solution below:

```
 if (@available(iOS 11.0, *))
 {
     [self.searchView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
     UILayoutGuide *guide = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide;

     [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
                                               [self.searchView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:guide.topAnchor],
                                               [self.searchView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:guide.leadingAnchor],
                                               [self.searchView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:guide.trailingAnchor],
                                               [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.searchView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:44]
                                               ]];
  }
```

Now everything looks great on all devices. Hope this helps someone else with the similar issue. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The [short videos Apple posted about iPhone X (and 8 and 8 Plus) development](https://developer.apple.com/videos/fall2017/) address this exact situation (or a couple that are very close to it).

In their case study of adapting the WWDC app for iPhone X, [they find that the search bar isn't set up right in the Videos tab](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/fall2017-201/?time=330). That's because they're `present`ing a `UISearchController`, but the best way to handle this in iOS 11 (for all devices) is to instead attach the search controller to the navigation item. If you still need to deploy back to iOS 10 (or earlier), you can handle this from an availability check:

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
// configure searchController properties

if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    searchController.isActive = true // to show it now
} else {
    present(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Likewise, if you're directly setting a search bar as the header for a table view, [you can attach it to the navigation item instead there, too](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/fall2017-201/?time=456):

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    searchController.isActive = shouldShowBarNow // made up local variable
} else {
    if shouldShowBarNow {
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    } else {
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil
    }
}
```